# How to successfully break out of function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, return

So I have a function that checks if the last character in a string is an arithmetic operator(+,-,*,/), and if it is it should immediately return from the function. If not, the subtract sign should be appended to the string. However, only the second case seems to be occurring and I can't figure out why. If anyone could provide some insight I would be very appreciative.

```
    $("#subtract").click(function () {
        var original=$("#display").text();
        var sliced=original.slice(0,original.length - 1);
        var signs=["+","-","*","/"];
        var charpos=sliced.charAt(sliced.length -1);

        if ((charpos === signs[0]) || (charpos === signs[1]) ||  (charpos  === signs[2]) || (charpos === signs[3])) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            var newdisplay=sliced + "-";
            $("#display").text(newdisplay);
        }

     });
```

Comment: It looks like you're getting the second-to-last character of `original` because you slice off the last character in `sliced` and get the last character of `sliced` with `charpos`. Is this intentional? If so, then I don't see what's wrong, so could you include an example of exactly what you inputted into `$("#display")` so I can test further?

Comment: Did you print them in your console and see if you get the characters correctly? `console.log()`

Comment: change `original.slice(0, original.length - 1)` to `original.slice(0, original.length)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're slicing the input which is removing the last character, then using `charAt` and getting the *second to last* character.

```
var original=$("#display").text(); // "foobar"
var sliced=original.slice(0,original.length - 1); // "fooba"
var charpos=sliced.charAt(sliced.length -1); // "a" -- we lost the "r"
```

You only need to call `charAt` and work with the last character (or, if you prefer `slice`, it's able to accept a negative number and backtrack the string).

Secondly, since `signs` is an array, you can use `indexOf` over checking each element. e.g.

```
var original = $('#display').text();
var signs = ["+","-","*","/"];
var lastChar = original.slice(-1); // OR original.charAt(original.length - 1);

// Check for the lastChar in the signs array
if (signs.indexOf(lastChar) != -1){ // -1 == not found
  return; // short exit
}
```

Comment: Thanks for indexOf technique for quickly scanning the array. I forgot that I was actually appending an additional value to #display before checking, but I fixed it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var original=$("#display").text();
var sliced=original.slice(0,original.length - 1);
```

the second line gets rid of the last character in your string. so you're not even able to check what that was. just get rid of it and change the first line to

```
var sliced=$("#display").text();
```

and everything should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if ((charpos === signs[0]) || (charpos === signs[1]) ||  (charpos  === signs[2]) || (charpos === signs[3])) {
        return;
    }
```

try

```
if ($.inArray(charpos, signs) > -1) {
    return;
}
```

First of all, never enumerate items from an array in such a fashion - it's easy to miss items that way. Secondly, exact instance comparison (===) won't fire, unless you compared exact same strings.

Besides, consider revising how you extract the last character.